# Can I prove that 2n+1 = O(2n)?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

Is 2n+1 = O(2n)? In other words, 2n+1 <= c * 2n  for any c and all n > n0?

I have plugged in numbers but none that worked. Obviously It is also (n) but I am trying to prove the above. Much appreciated.

Comment: $\frac{2n+1}{2n} = 1 + \frac 1{2n}$

Comment: As long as $f$ is nondecreasing, we always have $f + c \in O(f)$ for every constant $c$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n \geq 1$, $$2n+1 \leq 3n = \frac{3}{2}\cdot 2n.$$
Take $c=\frac{3}{2}$ and $n_0=1$.

---

Also, for the record: writing things like $O(2n)$ is "morally wrong." The whole point of the $O(\cdot)$ notation and its cousins ($\Omega(\cdot)$, $\Theta(\cdot)$, and so on) is to *hide* the constants to be able to focus on the asymptotic growth.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2n + 1}{2n} ~=~ 1 ~ \rightarrow ~ 2n + 1 \in \Theta(2n)$$